# Can I use my existing US visa to fly to USA from a different country?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, indian-citizens, b1-b2-visas, norway

I am on a work permit in Norway and I have a US tourist visa which I got when I was in India. Do I need any other visitor visa to fly from Norway to USA?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does your visa have an annotation stating that it is valid only for travel from India?

Comment: @Palak Will you be flying direct to USA or needing to transit?

Answer (score 12):

**Yes**, with your existing US visa, you can go to USA from any country. Your travel does not have to start from the country where you received the visa.

You do not require another visa for the same purpose whether you live in India or Norway now.

> - A visa issued for a single entry (denoted on the visa under “Entries” with the number 1) is valid, or can be used from the date it is issued until the date it expires to travel to a U.S. port-of-entry one time.
> - A visa issued for multiple entries (denoted under “entries” with a certain number (2, 3, etc.) or “M” for multiple/unlimited entries) is valid, or can be used from the date it is issued until the date it expires to travel to the U.S. port-of-entry as many times as your visa states, provided that:
>
>   - Applying for a new visa is not necessary if your visa has not expired and you have not exceeded the number of entries permitted on your visa.
>   - Multiple uses of a visa must be for the same purpose of travel allowable on the type of visa you have.

Source: [State Department](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/visa-expiration-date.html#2)

So as long as you fulfill that criteria you can safely use that visa from anywhere unless you have been advised not to.